# How to call Form 1's method from Form2 without static and new class();?

Tags: c#, image, methods, resize, call

How to call Form 1's method when Form is resized without static and new class(); like below codes. because more than one new class(); The "System.StackOverflowException" issue is causing when the code is used. it does not take the values it saves in the class due static.

Form1 class code:

```cs
Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
public void ResizePicture(int Height, int Width)
{
    frm2.pictureBox1.Height = Height;
    frm2.pictureBox1.Width = Width;
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    frm2.pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Omer\Desktop\screenshot.png");
    frm2.Show();
}
```

Form2 class code:

```cs
private void Form2_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ResizePicture(this.Height, this.Width);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can subscribe to the `Resize` event of the other form

In Form1:

```cs
private readonly Form2 frm2;

private Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    frm2 = new Form2();
    frm2.Resize += Frm2_Resize;
}

private void Frm2_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ...
}
```

This code only creates a Form2 once in the constructor of Form1. Now the Resize event handler of Form2 is in Form1.

---

Another possibility is to pass a reference of the first form to the second one

In Form2:

```cs
private readonly Form1 frm1;

private Form2(Form1 frm1)
{
    InitializeComponent();

    this.frm1 = frm1;
}

private void Form2_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    frm1.ResizePicture(this.Height, this.Width);
    // Note: `ResizePicture` must be public but not static!
}
```

In Form 1

```cs
frm2 = new Form2(this); // Pass a reference of Form1 to Form2.
```

Answer (score 0):

Another one, passing Form1 via `Show()` itself:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    frm2.pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Omer\Desktop\screenshot.png");
    frm2.Show(this); // <-- passing Form1 here!
}
```

In Form2, you cast `.Owner` back to Form1:

```
private void Form2_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form1 f1 = (Form1)this.Owner;
    f1.ResizePicture(this.Height, this.Width);
}
```

Comment: This is a good idea; however, it has the side effect that Form2 will always be displayed above Form1. See: [Form.Owner Property Remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.owner?view=windowsdesktop-6.0#remarks).

Comment: True! They are "linked" together. Minimizing/Restoring Form1 would make Form2 follow along with it. I like your event approach best @OlivierJacot-Descombes. Was just showing another option. This one requires the fewest changes in code, but isn't as strong as your two examples.